# Vector images extraction from PDF

Tags: java, pdf

is there any way to extract vector images from pdf using JAVA? I've tried with PDFBox, iText, and the only thing I'm getting is graphic which was put in PDF as a JPG or BMP?

Comment: Neither iText nor PDFBox has high level APIs for vector graphics export but in each case enhancing the architecture beneath the text extraction classes would allow such a functionality.

Comment: could You be more specific? Is there any other library which would support it out of the box?

Comment: To be more specific: Both iText and PDFBox use content Parsers and registerable callback objects for content operators for e.g. text extraction. You can implement callbacks for vector graphic operations which collect the operations and export them as a standalone file. You need to know some PDF content stream syntax and semantics, though... And on the other subject, I don't know the features of other PDF libraries.

Comment: How about Aspose.PDF I know it is not a free lib, but still. Do You have any experience with this?